# Query specific fields in 3 tables-PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have four tables (university, statistics, address, records)

University table has the following: (UName, Web Address, ID, (serves as PK)

Statistics: UniversityID, Division, 2012RankPosition,2011 RankPosition,2010 RankPosition,2009 RankPosition

Address: UniversityID, City, State, Zip code

Records: IDUniversity, Wins, Losses, Draw

I want to find all division 2 schools in New York and have their zip codes displayed as well. Can someone help me with this please? I am stuck.

Also, I want to find all division 2 schools that ranked in the top 10 for the past 4 seasons.
If someone has any input i would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First query try this... but i dont know if division 2 = new york...

```
Select *
FROM University 
JOIN Address on University.id = Address.UniversityID
JOIN Statistics on University.id = Statistics.UniversityID
WHERE Statistics.Division = 2
```

Second query depends on how you have stored the ranking ... if its just number 1 - best , 2,3 etc are worser

```
Select *
FROM University 
JOIN Statistics on University.id = Statistics.UniversityID
WHERE Statistics.Division = 2 
AND  2012RankPosition <= 10 
AND 2011RankPosition <= 10 
AND 2010RankPosition <= 10
AND 2009RankPosition <= 10
```

Hope that helps

Comment: If I wanted to query my records table and I wanted to display how many division 2 schools had greater wins then losses for the 2012 season, how would that look like?

Comment: actually the first query is displaying me schools from Connecticut, Pennsylvania, and New York. There is no indicator that it should search only schools in New York